# How do I add new search terms for items to Unity?

Tags: search

I want to type "cmd" and the terminal show up as result.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom shell script and then use the "export" command to save your custom path.

so something like /home/Blub/shellscripts/

and in that folder put your cmd.sh file...You can even make it executable and also you don't need the file extension .sh.

```
export PATH=/path/to/dir:$PATH
```

Optionally you can also go to your home folder and type ctrl+h to show hidden files and then open the .profile file.  You can then change the $PATH there.

Once you run it the program should be in your recent files in the dash as well.

You can also just create an alias for bash http://www.howtogeek.com/73768/how-to-use-aliases-to-customize-ubuntu-commands/